# Черный прямоугольник в alpha-пикселях png изображения

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Здравствуйте! Возникает проблема(пикрелейтед), если в одной области видимости создать и использовать 2(ну и больше, наверно) `Graphics`(в моём случае однин основан на `Image`, а второй на `HDC`). Проблема возникает с изображениями(`png`)с прозрачными пикселями изображения, нарисованного `Graphics::DrawImage()`. Происходит в 100% случаев сразу для всех изображений(но не сразу же при запуске программы, а после обновления(-й) окна). Всё время один и тот же чёрный прямоугольник

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    Image *im = new Bitmap(...);
    Graphics g(im);
    g.DrawImage(...);


    Graphics gq(hdcC);
    gq.DrawImage(...);
```

Comment: А какую библиотеку вы используете, неужели старенькую Borland? Может вам нужно подключить другую библиотеку? Укажите библиотеку версию, и фрагмент кода.

Comment: @nick_n_a, эмм да нет. Работаю в Visual Studio 2013, всё как у людей